# zenmap not opening

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I am running kali linux as a virtual machine in virtualbox, but when I click zenmap it does not open and nothing shows up, I have tried reinstalling it but the problem remains same.

when I run zenmap in terminal it shows:
`/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Obviously, Python is not installed or not in the PATH.

Comment: I have installed python3 but how do I add it to PATH in linux??

Answer (score 1):

`zenmap` has been removed from Kali Linux.

Here is the answer of Kali maintainer [@Gamb1t on kali forum](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?45988-Zenmap-missing-Kali-Linux-2019-4&p=89008#post89008).

> As zenmap was not being maintained upstream any longer we had to drop the package.

Zenmap is the nmap GUI, you should use `nmap` as alternative.

[nmap documentation.](https://nmap.org/docs.html)

Comment: So now what I have to learn nmap the commandline of zenmap or is there is any way??

Comment: @OjasvaNema Answer updated, `nmap` is the alternative. `nmap` CLI is more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a program named `python`. I just checked on my Kali installation (WSL2 running in Windows) and found that, indeed, it doesn't have `python` out of the box. So, create a symbolic link `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`, assuming that `/usr/bin/python3` is correct.

Normally, your PATH should contain /usr/bin. No need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build nmap from source in order to have zenmap accessible, head out to https://nmap.org/dist/ to download a bzip2 file containing the nmap's source code, for instance, for version 7.92, you can fetch the file [here](https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.92.tar.bz2) and signature [here](https://nmap.org/dist/sigs/nmap-7.92.tar.bz2.asc).

Then you can optionally also verify the signature. Inside the folder sigs, there are signatures for every file name, but the safest are the PGP ones, if you don't verify the signature, you may get a corrupted or maliciously tampered file.

To verify the signature, download the [nmap_gpgkeys](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/docs/nmap_gpgkeys.txt) and run:

```bash
gpg --import nmap_gpgkeys.txt
```

After it's done, download the asc file relevant to the version and the bzip one in an empty folder, to check it:

```bash
gpg --verify *.asc
```

Now if it displays GOOD, you are free to proceed, if it displays BAD, you should never install it

To install nmap from the source, run the following commands:

```bash
# MAKE SURE NMAP IN NOT INSTALLED

apt-get remove nmap

# Build nmap

bzip2 -cd nmap-*.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
cd nmap-*
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Note that you should have binutils and build-essential packages installed, it's good to have perl (for NSE), python2 and python3 as well. This command should be enough:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nmap
```

The last time I compiled nmap from source, there were some pretty interesting easter eggs in the build output, it may be worth checking out!